# Moduli space of stable principal $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$-bundles on a compact Riemann surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, moduli-space

Let $C$ be a compact Riemann surface with genus $2$. How can I describe the moduli space of stable principal $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$-bundles on $C$?

Comment: What is a stable $U(1)$-bundle? The definition of a stable principal bundle I know requires the structure group to be a complex (reductive) group and $U(1)$ is not a complex Lie group.

Comment: @studiosus I'm sorry... $SL(2)$

Comment: Arthur: Then you should rewrite the question including the title. You should also explain what "describe" means, for instance if you mean to describe as algebraic variety or as a topological space.

Comment: I took liberty editing your question to make it reflect what you are actually asking, accoring to discussion in comments. I also added the algebraic-geometry tag.